# Access report field truncating at 255 characters

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2003

I have a report whose record source is a query, say qryRecords.  In the report header I want to add a lengthy notes field (longer than 255 characters).  I have set up a table to hold these notes (with a field type "memo"), and because that table is separate from the record source for the report, I was going to put the Notes field in the report using VBA code.

In the open event of the report, I have added this code:

```
Dim rst as Recordset
Dim sql_qry as String

sql_qry = "SELECT notes FROM tblNotes WHERE id = 1;"
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql_qry)

rst.MoveFirst
Me.txtNote = rst![notes]  'I get the run-time error on this line
```

Unfortunately I get a run-time error where noted ("You can't assign a value to this object").  I found a person with a similar issue on a form, and the suggestion was to move the code from the open event to the OnCurrent event, but that event doesn't exist for a report.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

--- Original Question ---

I have a form with an unbound text box (txtNotes), and when the user opens the form, the text box is populated with text that is longer than 255 characters (it concatenates various fields from the database).  This works with no problem.

There's a button on the form that opens a report, and in the report, I set the Control Source for a text box to Forms![frmMain]![frmSub]![txtNotes], which is the text box mentioned above.  That works too, but for some reason the text on the report is truncated at 255 characters.  The form's text box is unbound, so there's no underlying table to limit the length.  Does anybody know why this would happen or if there's a workaround?

Comment: What database are you using to store your data?

Comment: I'm using tables within the same Microsoft Access database.  Sorry, I see I didn't mention that in the write-up.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely when the data from the field is being cast as a Text type rather than as a Memo. Really there's no way to explicitly cast a Text as a Memo (you can go the other way around though with CStr). I had problems with truncation on the form as well when experimenting with this scenario.

I'd suggest you are probably generating this field on the form in the wrong way. Dollars to doughnuts you could generate it in a query (used in the form's Control Source), rather than concatenating it together and placing into an unbound field. Likewise, you could then use that same query as the control source for the report that you are opening.

If all of that is truly impossible, I'd point you at dumping the values from the form into a table specifically for the report and then using the table as a control source for the report.

---- Edit ----

I still contend that you can add it to your Report's data source. In my example below, I've tacked on tblNotes to a select on the Bar table.

```
SELECT bar.f0, bar.f1, bar.f2, bar.f3, tblNotes.notes 
FROM bar, tblNotes 
WHERE tblNotes.id = 1;
```

Yes, if there is 300 rows of Bar, you'll get 300 copies of the same Notes field, but that's a minor problem.

Form there, you just make txtNote's data source the tblNotes.Notes column. txtNote can certainly exist in the report/page header, and when MS Access generates it, it will only use one row. I'm not sure if picks the first/last row, or random row - never the less since they are all the same, it doesn't matter.

Comment: I think that's a great suggestion!  Unfortunately these text fields on the report act as notes above the actual data, so the report's record source has to be a different query.  I did try to put the data in a table though and then populate the text box on the report from the table, but Access won't let me do it.  I used:  "Me.txtNote = rst![notes]", and got an error: "You can't assign a value to this object."  The code was in the open event of the report.  Any suggestions?  Can I set the text box to have a control source that's different from the record source of the overall report?  Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you can edit the question, and include an example of what your source data looks like (anonymise it if you like), and what you expect the report to look like.

Comment: I have edited the question to try to better explain my new problem.  Thanks for any help!