# Access report text box only displays 255 characters of a longer query result

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2016

I have what seems to be a common issue but the specifics are a bit different than other questions available.  Working in a MS Access 2016 database on Windows 10.

I have a query performing a UDP function Coalesce which combines Long Text from multiple records into a single String.  The query does not appear to be limited in size at all - I can view the correct output of hundreds of characters.

However when i try to display this in a report, in a text box with Can Grow, only the first 255 characters are visible.  (Text box is growing correctly)

There is no formatting at all set to this text box, and it is set to Plain Text (so it can shrink, which apparently Rich Text cannot do.  Also Rich text has the same problem)

Many solutions center around getting the query to return more than 255 characters ([Why a Long Text field is returning only 255 characters in a MS ACCESS 2013 query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19984934/why-a-long-text-field-is-returning-only-255-characters-in-a-ms-access-2013-query)) - I do not have this problem. The query is ok.

Many solutions center around a record source from a table of type Short Text, or a query from a Short Text field ([Access report field truncating at 255 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817136/access-report-field-truncating-at-255-characters)).  This is also not my problem since a) the original source field is long text, it is processed through a UDP which outputs a String type, and the query result is >255 characters.

Help!

Comment: Does the report perhaps GROUP by this column? (see Grouping and Sorting). -- See also: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html

Comment: It does not. This column is a summary of comments linked to a record - so it can be anywhere from 0 to n lines long and is not sorted or grouped at all.

Comment: Is the report RecordSource a query that references the query with the concatenation? Did you read the Allen Browne tutorial? He mentions a bug when returning more than 255 characters and links to a possible solution. Try calling concatenation function directly in textbox.

Comment: Yes! @June7 Moving the coalesce formula into the report textbox directly solved the problem! Would you want to move that to an answer?  Regarding the Allen Browne link, I did read it but I got to "If your query displays the memo correctly, the values are truncated when exported, you have struck another set of issues." and the links below either didn't work or didn't help me figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the report RecordSource is a query that references the query with the concatenation, you may encounter the bug described by Allen Browne's ConcatRelated function article http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html where he offers possible solution.

However, the function can be called from a textbox or in another VBA procedure. Options to try so results are not passed query to query:

1. reference query object with the concatenation by name directly as RecordSource
2. construct SQL statement with the concatenation function directly in RecordSource
3. call concatenation function directly in textbox